# How can I find a specific link in the HTML response Code with the name?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have a html link structure like that `<a href=dynamicURL>LinkName</a>`.
I want to extract the `LinkName`, so I can take the dynamic URL from the link for next HTML Request.

Is there any solution with a script or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) with the regex:

`<a\shref=([^>]+)>LinkName<\/a>`

*`\s` = space

`[^>]+` = everything not equal to >

`\/` = escaping the forward slash*

Try [this site](http://rubular.com/), it makes learning regular expressions easy.